# Xcode, images won't load into UIImageView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiimage

I just updated to Xcode 7.3, not sure if that's related. I'm attempting to display png or jpeg images in a `UIImageView` using code. The images I had installed before updating appear fine. The new images show nil when I query the unsuccessful attempt to load. The images appear fine if I load them into the Asset catalog but there are three reasons I'd rather avoid doing that.

BTW, am using `UIImage(named: _)` to attempt to load.
Edit: It appears the issue is restricted to JPEGs. The initial PNG I tried, which I've used for years in a nib view, wouldn't load but other PNG's I just created seem to load OK. Since almost all my images will be PNG's I'm good to go but still curious.

Comment: Check your "Copy Bundle Resources" list (in your target settings > Build Phases) - make sure the images are there.

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct code to add the images to a UIImageView. In my experience, this can be really temperamental: something that doesn't give an error and looks like it should work just does not work. `ImageOutlet.image = UIImage(named: "imagename")`. Make sure `imagename` does not have a filetype. So, `imagename` should be "image" not "image.png".

Comment: Thanks guys. Checked the Bundle Resources. No filetype tag. Have you seen this work on Xcode 7.3? I know somewhere along the way it became imperative to use Assets to display images in certain Nib objects such as segmented controls. I'm wondering if Apple has extended that hastle to other image uses as well.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you've put your image in the project and can see it in you navigation area, you should be able to use it like this.

```
var imageView: UIImageView!
var yourImage: UIImage!



func yourFunction() {

    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)
    self.yourImage = UIImage(named: "yourImageName.jpg")

    self.imageView.image = self.yourImage

}
```